# No such method when attempting to retrive fromjavax.servlet.http.Part getSubmittedFileNam()

Tags: java, servlets

Okay, I'm using javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.  When I expand, it clearly show Part.class and "getSubmittedFileName().

Yet I get this error...

```
exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:       javax.servlet.http.Part.getSubmittedFileName()Ljava/lang/String;
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

No error is indicated in the Eclipse java code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition>
        <div id="colBottom">
        <h:panelGroup>
             <h:inputFile id="uploadFileId" image="/images/open.gif" value="#    {mainBean.uploadFile}"/>
             <h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{mainBean.clickUpload}"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
        </div>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Below is the java code attempting to parse the Part.  Strangely enough, I can open the input stream and convert to text.  I need to be able to determine if the file is a .zip file so chilkat can unzip it.

```
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@ManagedBean(name="mainBean")
@SessionScoped 
public class MainBean {

    Part uploadFile;
    String notesText;

    public MainBean() {
    }

    public String clickUpload() {
        try {
            String fileName = Paths.get(getUploadFile().getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();           
            long uploadFileSize = getUploadFile().getSize();
            InputStream is = getUploadFile().getInputStream();
            byte[] uploadBytes = new byte[(int)uploadFileSize];
            int bytesRead = is.read(uploadBytes);
            setNotesText(new String(uploadBytes));
            is.close();
        
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "display";
    }
```

Comment: *"I'm using javax.servlet-api-3.1.0"*: it's normally be the target runtime who's using that. So even if you include Servlet 3.1 JAR in the WAR, when you deploy to a Servlet 3.0 runtime (e.g. Tomcat 7) then it won't automagically become a Servlet 3.1 runtime. You need to upgrade the runtime itself.

Answer (score 0):

I still do not understand why the method doesn't work, but

```
str = getUploadFile().getContentType();
```

... reveals the file type "application/x-zip-compressed"

That's all I need.